# dgrid does not sort when using pagination

Tags: dgrid

I have a dgrid (version 1.10) that on startup sorts on two properties.  The grid is paginated.  When items are inserted in the store (RequestMemory that is Trackable) the items on the second page are not sorted property.

[image: img]

Comment: Are you sorting the data or the grid column after setting the grid store? If you are setting the store first and then sorting. only the records related to the current page will be sorted. It is good to sort before updating the store as the sorting happens across all pages.

Comment: I have a an initial sort when the grid is created,<pre> var grid = window.grid = new CustomGrid({
                    collection: store,
                    //className: 'dgrid-autoheight',
                    sort: [{property:'type'},{property:'averageCarrierFrequency'}], // Initialize sort on last name, ascending
                    columnSets: getColumnSets(),
                    allowSelectAll: true,
                    loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
                    noDataMessage: 'No results found.'
                }, 'grid');</pre>

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of second page? where the sorting is not proper.